# The type 'SecurityTokenDescriptor' exists in both Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens, Version=6.26.1.0 & Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0

Tags: .net-core, .net-6.0

The type 'SecurityTokenDescriptor' exists in both Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens, Version=6.26.1.0, culture=neutral and Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral

Microsoft.IdentityModel never used and not available in solution cs file.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had and resolved this issue. I was working on uploading files to SharePoint and installed a deprecated package that caused the issue. I removed the package, and it cleared up the error, package for me was SharePointPnPCoreOnline version 3.28.2012. Very bizarre though.